# How to realize optionally empty parameters when defining a custom RouteEnhancer of type "Plugin" with Typo3 9.5 LTS site configuration?

Tags: php, routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

I want to migrate an older extension to Typo3 9.5. and wonder how to configure optional URL parameters.

Using 'defaults' allows to leave out parameters at the end, but how do I allow to leave out parameters in the middle, like `example.com/filter//foo/bar` or `example.com/filter/foobar//bar`.

This is my site configuration. It works well with parameters.

```
routeEnhancers:
  filter:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/filter/{param0}/{param1}/{param2}'
    namespace: 'tx_myextension_myplugin'
    defaults:
      param0: ''
      param1: ''
      param2: ''
    aspects:
      param0:
        type: MyValueMapper
      param1:
        type: MyValueMapper
      param2:
        type: MyValueMapper
```

It is not an Extbase extension, so the controller works like this. In real I have some more params.

```
class MyController extends ActionController{
  public function filterAction() {
    // $this->request->getArgument('param0');
    // $this->request->getArgument('param1');
    // $this->request->getArgument('param2');
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the parameter "requirements" which came a bit later so it is not included in many examples out there. Sorry, I cannot answer in more detail now: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html

Comment: Thumbs up for your very good description and minimum viable example!

Comment: Thanks @jonas-eberle  I tried different combinations of 'defaults', 'requirements' and 'aspects'. Even using `requirements: param0: '[0-9]{1,3}' results in an cHash-Error, if I don't add an aspect.

Comment: If I use `param0: '.{0,}'` as requirement and NO aspect, I can use an empty parameter. But if I use a non-empty parameter I'll get a cHash error. I guess aspects and requirements are not designed to be combined?

Comment: Funny! With requirements of `'.{0,}'` my first parameter (`$this->request->getArgument('param0')`) is `000/111/222` when calling `example.com/filter/000/111/222`. Okay, I could use a regex like `'[^\/]{0,}'`for the requirements definition. But is this a bug or a feature?!?

Comment: requirements are supposed to work with aspects.
If you have a working example, you can post it as an aswer to your own question. As the official documentation is still lacking in that area, we should go through it and correct/amend the documentation.

Comment: Okay, so I now think that something is buggy with requirements. I uploaded a test extension at github https://github.com/jkujku/juku_siteconf My solution is to use this regex '[^\/]{0,}' and to exclude the params from chash. I don't think it is a real solution...